# Why am I not able to type anything on Arduino Ide 1.8.13

Tags: arduino-ide

[image: This is an image of the ide]

Hi, I am using the Arduino 1.8.13 ide, and I am unable to type anything into the sketch. The whole program is highlighted in blue, and I am unable to type anything. I have no idea what happened, and I really need help. I've tried downloading the app and redownloading, I tried changing the settings, nothing worked. Please help me.

Here's what works:

-Serial Monitor

-All the Settings Above

-Opening the Menus

-Uploading Code

-Saving

-Compressing

Basically, everything in the Arduino IDE works fine except being able to edit the code.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your systemwide Java version up-to-date? Does the rest of the Ardunio IDE work as-expected (e.g. can you open menus and open the serial-port monitor?)

Comment: Yes, it all works except being able to edit the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have "Use external editor" enabled, which puts the Ardunio IDE's text-editor in read-only mode.

Go File > Preferences > Settings > [ ] Use external editor

Ensure it is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much! You have no idea how much trouble I would be in if it wasn't working! I'll give you the bounty when I am able to! Thanks.